# Different notices for the unanswered question

Tags: support, design, testing

I posted a [question in MSO](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341290) about adding style to the Can you help? text. This text will appear for those posts that don't have any answer yet, like:

> Can you help? Stack Overflow depends on everyone sharing their knowledge. If you're able to answer this question, please do!

But in the [comments](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341290/add-styling-for-can-you-help-text?noredirect=1#comment430787_341290), some users are still seeing the old help text, like:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

Based on what logic is the different notice appearing? or is the notice appearing randomly to users for an [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing)?

**Note:** The notice is not specific to SO; it is showing for most of the Stack Exchange sites, so I'm posting the question here.

Screenshots are from the comments section of the MSO question:

[image: New notice]

---

[image: Old notice]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message there is currently being A/B tested, which is why different people (well, things like user agent are involved, so same person on a different browser, for instance) are seeing different things.

Comment: How are you determining "success" in an A/B test like this? Based on whether or not the question gets an answer?

Comment: @CodyGray - a few different metrics. One is which one is getting more answers, another which one gets better answer quality.

Comment: what is the definitions of better answer quality, beside higher number of votes?